# Import existing file or directory into intellij idea project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, intellij-idea, npm

I'm using Intellij Idea 15.0.3. I tried to use it to develop a MEAN stack application.

I first `File -> New -> Project -> Empty Project` to create an empty project. Then in Intellij Idea's terminal I type `npm init -y`, a `package.json` is generated. However, when I tried to edit this generated `package.json`, a window pops up, saying: `These files do not belong to the project`, and asks me if I want to edit it anyway.

Also, after I edited the `package.json`, I run `npm install` in the terminal, a new directory `node_modules` is generated, but it's not shown in the Intellij Idea.

How can I add `package.json` and `node_modules` into project? Do I have to manually created file or folder through Intellij Idea project UI and give up using its terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new project from existing source so..

File->New Project - Select HTML5/Javascript application then select one of the options at the bottom with "Existing Sources" at the end of it, you then just specify the folder that it's already and in and you should be good to go.